# correct way to write to the same file from multiple processes awk

Tags: awk, parallel-processing

The title says it all.
I have 4 awk processes logging to the same file, and output seems fine, not mangled, but I'm not sure that just redirecting `print` output like this: `print "xxx" >> file` in every process is the right way to do it.

There are many similar questions around the site, but this one is particularly about awk and a pragmatic, code-correct way to approach the problem.

**EDIT**

Sorry folks, of course I wasn't "just redirecting" like I wrote, I was appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not safe.

the awk `print "foo" > "file"` will open the file and overwrite the file content, till the end of script.

That is, if your 4 awk processes started writing to the same file on different time, they overwrite the result of each other.

To reproduce it, you could start two (or more) awk like this:

```
awk '{while(++i<9){system("sleep 2");print "p1">"file"}}' <<<"" &
awk '{while(++i<9){system("sleep 2");print "p2">"file"}}' <<<"" &
```

and same time you monitoring the content of `file`, you will see finally  there are not exactly 8 "p1" and 8 "p2".

using `>>` could avoid the losing of entries. but the entry sequence from 4 processes could be messed up.

**EDIT**

Ok, the `>` was a typo.

I don't know why you really need 4 processes to write into same file. as I said, with `>>`, the entries won't get lost (if you awk scripts works correctly). however personally I won't do in this way. If I have to have 4 processes, i would write to different files. well I don't know your requirement, just speaking in general.

outputting to different files make the testing, debugging easier.. imagine when one of your processes had problem, you want to solve it. etc...

Comment: I was appending, thanks for making me notice I wrote the question wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I think using the operating system print command is save. As in fact this will append the file write buffer with the string you provide as log. So the system will menage the actual writing process of the data to disc, also if another process will want to use the same file the system will see that the resource is already claimed and will wait for 1st thread to finish its processing, than will allow the 2nd process to write to the buffer.